# Any way to query CRM Content Subscriptions?

Tags: soql, data-loader, content, workbench

I was wondering if CRM Content subscription information is stored anywhere. I am trying to find which users are subscribed to a particular tag.

This object is the only thing I have come up with as a possibility

http://www.salesforce.com/us/developer/docs/api/Content/sforce_api_objects_entitysubscription.htm

but was not able to find it in any WorkBench or DataLoader.

Comment: You should be able to find EntitySubscription if you're using the latest API Version. I'd think EntitySubscription is right, certainly is the object that holds Chatter followers.

Answer (score 2):

I had the same question. I found that EntitySubscription is only available if you have chatter enabled.

Answer (score 1):

You can query content subscriptions from the ContentDocumentHistory object filtering on field "Field" with the value "contentDocSubscribed"

```
   SELECT Id, ContentDocumentId, CreatedById, CreatedBy.Name, CreatedDate, Field 
   FROM ContentDocumentHistory where Field = 'contentDocSubscribed'
```

Answer (score 0):

I was researching on it and found that content can subscribed at three levels,

```
ContentWorkSpace
ContentTag
ContentDocument
```

and the corresponding Content subscriptions are residing in objects:

```
ContentWorkspaceSubscription
ContentTagSubscription
ContentDocumentSubscription
```